# System limitation on configured product price

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, price

I noticed Magento doesn't allow a price above 100,000,000.00 (whatever currency), and if you try to go above that, it will default to 100,000,000.00. This is reasonable for USD, but not for currencies who's exchange rate is thousands times greater than the USD.

Is this a configuration in Magento that I can modify, or am I stuck with this price limitation? If I could set the limit to 999,999,999.99 I would be fine (same number of digits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the database.
All the decimal fields (including price fields) are `DECIMAL (12,4)`. This means you are allowed to enter a number with 8 (12 - 4) digits before the decimal point and 4 digits after the decimal point. (max value 99,999,999.9999 that may be converted to 100,000,000.0000 when using it in PHP scripts)
In order to be able to add values above the max value you need to alter the decimal fields in all the tables in the database. and make them `DECIMAL (13,4)` or bigger.
The most important tables (in my opinion) are `catalog_product_entity_decimal`, all the tables that start with `catalog_product_index_price` and all the tables that start with `sales_flat`, but I recommend changing all of them for consistency.
Clear the cache when you are done because the table definitions are cached even if the cache is turned off.